# Not able to set lang in zsh macos

Tags: macos, locale, zsh, macos-catalina, lang

I need my lang to be set to en_US.UTF-8

I followed a lot of threads and resources on stackoverflow as well as other resources but none of them worked for me.

Here is the issue :

I am using 10.15.1 MacOs Catalina and have set Zsh as my default shell.

Here are the profile files :

**~/.zshrc**

```
export PATH="/Applications/flutter/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH":"/Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
export LC_ALL="en-US.UTF-8"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

**~/.profile**

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

**~/.bash_profile**

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 5.2.0 installer
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

#For flutter
export PATH="/Applications/flutter/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH":"/Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
export LC_ALL="en-US.UTF-8"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#setting for ruby
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
```

**Here is the output of locale :**

```
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL="C"
```

I need everything to be set to en_US.UTF-8, how do i do it ?

Comment: The only file that's relevant here is `.zshrc`, and you haven't set `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in that file.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should set environment variables in `.zprofile` rather than `.zshrc` (although because `zsh` sources both files in a login shell, unlike `bash` which only sources `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`, it only really matters if you plan on starting non-login shells).

Comment: I'd rather use `.zshenv` which is sourced even in non-interactive mode. Nicer for scripts who "reads" outputs...

Comment: @levif For environment variables, you don't *want* to set them every time you start a new shell. Let them be inherited. `.zshenv` is for things that can't be inherited.

Comment: @chepner you're right about `.zshenv` ! One can read [zsh doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html) or a good [StackExchange topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) for more information on how people use those files.

Answer (score 1):

First, only `.zshrc` is relevant; the other two files are not used by `zsh` at all.

I don't fully understand how locales work, and how they work in macOS specifically, but the solution would appear to be to set `LANG` in your `.zshrc` file.

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

That said, you should put environment variables in `.zprofile`, rather than `.zshrc`, because they only need to be set once. Any non-login shell that would only execute `.zshrc` will inherit environment variables from the parent; they don't need to be set again. (It's less important with `zsh` than with `bash`, which only sources `.bash_profile` for a login shell, not it and `.bashrc`. `zsh` will source both files automatically)

Comment: I edited the above to use `"en_US.UTF-8"` instead of the previous version (`"en-US.UTF-8"`, without an underscore)